# G++ on visual studio code, can run programs but not debug

Tags: g++, vscode-debugger

Whenever i try to debug it tells me
"launch: program c:filepath\build\debug\outdebug" does not exist

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "c:/Users/name/CSC",
      "program": "c:/Users/name/CSC/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

task.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "windows-gcc-x86",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "${default}",
            "cppStandard": "${default}",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86",
            "compilerArgs": [
                ""
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I dont understand why i can run programs, but debugging gives me the errors. tried re-installing g++, same errors. Ive gone to the launch.json "program": "c:/Users/name/CSC/build/Debug/outDebug", file location and there is no build file much less a debug file so its being directed to a non-existent file location for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises where the C/C++ Runner extension is installed but not used to build the app. The C/C++ Runner extension automatically creates a configuration ("C/C++ Runner: Debug Session") in launch.json but that fails if C/C++ Runner was not used to build the cpp file. The solution is to either build the app using C/C++ Runner (which creates the missing folders/files) or add (then use) an alternative configuration in launcher.json.

Documentation for building project using C/C++ Runner: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=franneck94.c-cpp-runner